# Why is Word 2007 not allowing me to select or edit above text with cursor?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have a problem selecting or editing text in Word 2007 which is above the cursor's current position. I am unable to select any text or even just click in the upper part of the document text, but I am able to edit the text using the arrow keys going up, left, right, or down again.

It is irrelevant if it is an existing or a new document, how long or short the text is or how many lines the text has.

Example: I can create a new text, type a few words each line. 
If I try to click into the top of the text - not able to do.
If I try to select any text - unable to do.
If I try and use arrow keys up or left - no problem and I can edit text.

The document is not protected, no tracking changes selected, not read only...

This does only happens in MS Word 2007. I can edit everything and move the cursor round in MS Excel, Power Point and even Open Office.

Any idea?

Comment: Here's some similar problems (and proposed solutions) http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/officesetupdeploylegacy/thread/2524103f-a8ad-40eb-b762-2e67411dbbc1

Comment: Why don't you reinstall Word?